# Why does my palindrome checking function always return false for palindromes?

Tags: c, string, palindrome, sentence

I'm trying to check if a sentence is palindrome or not. Neither space nor    punctuation matter.

Examples:

• Never odd or even

• A man a plan a canal Panama.

• Gateman sees name, garageman sees name tag

Netheir of this sentences passes true on my code. 
On my first for I try to remove spaces, punctuation and transform upper letters in lower.

```
int palindrome(char *str){
    int n,n2 = 0,i,j=0;
    n = sizeof(str)/sizeof(char);
    char nova[n];

    for (i=0;i< n;i++){
        if(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z'){
            nova[n2] = ('a' + str[i] - 'A');
            n2++;
        }
        else if(str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z'){
            nova[n2] = str[i];
            n2++;
        }
    }

    i=0;
    while (i < n2-1){
        if (nova[i]!= nova[j]){
            return 0;
        }
        i++;
        j--;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: start with figuring out what `sizeof(str)` does..

Comment: ... vs `strlen(str)`.

Comment: I can´t use strlen()

Comment: Then do it yourself via a walked `const char*`. Either way, `sizeof(str)` is *not* what you use here.

Comment: You shouldn't edit the code in your question, especially to remove lines that people are pointing out, like the `sizeof` line. I'd recommend reverting your edit.

Comment: I rolled back the edits. The question and existing answer are less confusing this way. Please ask a new question if you have problems with your updated code.

Comment: @Daniel C.: Just because you "can´t use strlen()", `sizeof` will not somehow magically work for your purposes.

Comment: per your examples, capitialzed characters must be treaded as matching lower case characters but the question does not state that requirement.  Strongly suggest add `#include <ctype.h> them use the `tolower()` function to get all lower case letters.

Comment: NOTE: the expression: `sizeof(str)` is getting the size of a pointer.  Suggest using the `strlen()` function

Comment: the code block, beginning with: `for (i=0;i< n;i++){`  can be reduced to: `for( int i=0; i<n; i++ ) { nova[i] = tolower(str[i]; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existing answer is good, but there is another way to solve this problem, without using additional allocated memory. You don't really need to store the letters anywhere in order to compare them - you can use pointers to your original string.

```
int palindrome(char *str)
{
    int i = 0, j = strlen(str);
    while (i < j)
    {
        if (str[j] == '\0' || !isalpha(str[j]))
            --j; // skip the character on the right if it's not a letter
        else if (!isalpha(str[i]))
            ++i; // skip the character on the left if it's not a letter
        else if (tolower(str[i]) != tolower(str[j]))
            return 0; // letters are different? - not a palindrome
    }
    // all letters were equal? - a palindrome
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: That solution is better, thanks. But i can't use functions already defined in this case.

Comment: problem with this answer, a space will evaluate to true when calling `isalpha()`

Answer (score 3):

line 4: you want to get the count of elements by `sizeof`.

But if you transfer your arguments to function by pointer.

```
  n = sizeof(str)/sizeof(char);
```

n will always be 4 (on 32 bit platforms). Instead, use

```
  n = strlen(str)
```

(need to `#include <string.h>`) if it is a string format in c.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now with all the modifications it works. Thanks guys.

```
int palindrome(char *str)
{
int n =0,i=0,j;
char nova[100];

while(str[i]!= '\0'){
  if(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z'){
         nova[n] = ('a' + str[i] - 'A');
         n++;
  }
  else if(str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z'){
         nova[n] = str[i];
         n++;
  }
  i++;
}

i=0;
j= n-1;
while (i< j){
    if (nova[i]!= nova[j]){
        return 0;
    }
    i++;
    j--;
}

return 1;
}
```

Comment: this does NOT work when the string is greater than 100 characters long

Comment: There are other character sets, like EBCDIC .   The question does not state a requirement that the ASCII  character set is used, so this answer fails for anything but ASCII.